# Dealing with Maps

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a districting project. the goal of the project is to partition a given country/state into a a set of districts. each district is a set of counties that are adjacent to each other.
I need a way to show the results in a visual way. So, am thinking of displaying the map of the country and coloring each district in a different color, but i have no idea how to do this! is there libraries that help me do this?

I am implementing the project using WPF. i haven't started any visual coding. i just implemented the algorithm of the districting. So am open for any suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried?  If you don't even know where to start then you need some more practice learning the WPF API.  This question is overly vague.

Comment: thats true. I need to learn more about WPF, but please help me in narrowing down what to read an learn by providing links to tutorials that are related to what i want "Maps".

Comment: Well, looking for tutorials telling you how to create maps is likely going to be too narrow.  However, if you read up on how to create custom visuals in WPF, how to use types such as Path and and different Geometries then you should be able to use that knowledge to do what you need.  Like everything else, you need to start at the beginning and work your way up.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent free WPF beginner's guide over on CodeProject... [WPF: A Beginner's Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF1.aspx)

Once you go through all the parts check out [Creating and consuming a custom WPF control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_CustomerControl.aspx) followed by reading Sacha's other WPF [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=569009)... list of his articles is literally a WPF treasure trove.

Once you go through all that you ought to be more than ready to tackle this problem...